# Search scope to rails application query with joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

good I am trying to create a scope to search the records of an associated model through the attributes of the associated model, as well as the attributes of the model itself.

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :payment_issuer, class_name: 'Balance', foreign_key: 'payment_issuer_id', optional: true
  belongs_to :payment_reciever, class_name: 'Balance', foreign_key: 'payment_reciever_id'
  belongs_to :closure, optional: true

  validates_presence_of :amount, :reference, :status

  scope :for_commerce, -> (commerce) { Payment.joins(payment_reciever: {user: :commerce}).where(
      payment_recievers: {
        users: {
          commerce: commerce
        }
      }
    ) 
  }
  scope :billed_at, -> (date) { where("payments.status ILIKE 'Pago' AND payments.created_at >=?", date) }
  scope :refills, -> { where("payments.status ILIKE 'Recarga'") }
end
```

this is the balance model

```
class Balance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :issued_payments, class_name: 'Payment', foreign_key: 'payment_issuer_id'
  has_many :recieved_payments, class_name: 'Payment', foreign_key: 'payment_reciever_id'

  validates_presence_of :amount
end
```

and this is the user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
         
  belongs_to :commerce, optional: true
  has_one :balance

  validates_presence_of :name, :phone, :rif_type,
                        :rif_number, :role, :email
  
  scope :admin, -> { where( "users.role ILIKE 'Admin' OR users.role ILIKE 'Superadmin'" ) }
  scope :search, -> (search) {
    where(
      "users.name ILIKE '%#{search}%' OR users.rif_number ILIKE '%#{search}%' OR users.email ILIKE '%#{search}%'"
    )
  }
end
```

I already tried this

```
  scope :search, -> (search) { Payment.joins(payment_issuer: :user).where(payment_issuers: { users: { name: search } }, "payments.reference": search) }
```

but dont return any record, even when I enter exact values

these is the return

```
Payment Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments" INNER JOIN "balances" ON "balances"."id" = "payments"."payment_issuer_id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "balances"."user_id" WHERE "users"."name" = $1 AND "payments"."reference" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["name", "1605895669"], ["reference", "1605895669"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
```

and i also tried

```
  scope :search, -> (search) { Payment.joins(payment_issuer: :user).where("payments.reference ILIKE '#{search}' OR payments.payment_issuers.users.name ILIKE '#{search}'") }
```

but return

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: payments.payment_issuers.users.name)
LINE 1: ...E (payments.reference ILIKE 'Esteban Chirinos' OR payments.p...
```

thank you very much and I hope your answers

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, please add it to your question. I think your `where` statement is incorrect, but without that information it is hard to say for sure.

Comment: does not return any record even when I enter values ​​that already exist

Comment: Why on earth are you doing `users.role ILIKE 'Admin'`? Normalize your data...

Comment: @max explain me how normalize my data

Comment: Ensure that you're not storing 'admin' and 'Admin' for example in a status column so that you don't need to use ilike or or even like. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: `payments.payment_issuers.users.name` should just be `users.name` in your query right now it thinks you are calling [database_name].[schema].[table].[column] which is the normal format for cross database queries. Instead you just want [table].[column] because the joins handle the references to the payments table and the payment_issuers table

Comment: @engineersmnky Thank you very much, that was the solution to the problem